# Can you become a CFI with only a PPL (EASA)?

Tags: easa-regulations, ppl, cfi

In Europe, can you get your CFI rating with a PPL only or do you need a CPL?

I assume that if you get paid to do flight instruction it's considered a commercial activity, so you'll need a CPL. But what if you do instruction without getting paid, do you still need a commercial licence to be a CFI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The EASA requirements for a CFI ticket are](http://barcelonaflightschool.com/pilot-training/flight-instructor-fi-course/):

- Over 18 yo
- Hold a Commercial Pilot License or a Private Pilot License with the CPL theory done.
- A minimum flight experience of 200 hours as a Pilot of which 150 will be as Pilot in Command
- Hold a Medical Certificate Class I or II in accordance with
  the license